# How to dump all MySQL databases for one specific user?

Tags: mysql, database, mysqldump

I need to export a particular user's databases so that they can take them to a different server.  I have 30 or so users and many dozens of databases.  This particular user alone has about 20 or so.

How can I easily export all the databases for just this specific user?  I've been looking at `mysqldump` but it seems to require that I specify the databases individually.  Is there a way to just dump them all at once into separate .sql files, but just for the one user?

A few notes:

1. users do not have SSH/CLI access
2. There is a problem currently preventing me from exporting via PHPMyAdmin
3. This user's account has been compromised so I want to get him off the server ASAP, but give him his DBs so he can rebuild elsewhere

Comment: Why don't you just let the user do this if its their database?  I mean tools like `phpmyadmin` were made for this exact purpose.

Comment: For starters the users don't have command line access.  Secondly there is an issue with PHPMyAdmin and exports right now and I'm trying to just work around it until it's fixed.  Third, this user's account has been compromised in a very bad way and I need him gone as quickly as possible, but I want to give him his DBs so he can try to rebuild elsewhere.

Comment: That is all helpful information.  Update your question so my comment can be deleted.